# Virtualbox machine cannot ping its own public IP

Tags: virtualbox, ip, firewall, ping, icmp

I have a strange problem. I have a bridged network adapter on my virtualbox machine (Kali Linux) - with assigned IP address with my local LAN pool (192.168.0.22) and I can ping e.g google.com (DNS works) but I cannot ping my own public IP.

I wanted to test OpenVPN Server but from client installed on my host machine (Windows 7) I cannot set my public IP as remote address, instead I have to set 192.168.0.22 (LAN IP)

Is this problem with firewall which block something? ( I set iptables -F and still no success)